# Javascript Cookie Function not working for Domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Here are the functions Im using:

Set Cookie:

```
function set_cookie ( name, value, exp_y, exp_m, exp_d, path, domain, secure )
{
  var cookie_string = name + "=" + escape ( value );

  if ( exp_y )
  {
    var expires = new Date ( exp_y, exp_m, exp_d );
    cookie_string += "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString();
  }

  if ( path )
        cookie_string += "; path=" + escape ( path );

  if ( domain )
        cookie_string += "; domain=" + escape ( domain );

  if ( secure )
        cookie_string += "; secure";

  document.cookie = cookie_string;
}
```

Read Cookie:

```
function get_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
  var results = document.cookie.match ( '(^|;) ?' + cookie_name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)' );

  if ( results )
    return ( unescape ( results[2] ) );
  else
    return null;
}
```

Delete Cookie:

```
function delete_cookie ( cookie_name )
{
  var cookie_date = new Date ( );  // current date & time
  cookie_date.setTime ( cookie_date.getTime() - 1 );
  document.cookie = cookie_name += "=; expires=" + cookie_date.toGMTString();
}
```

The Jquery I use to construct the cookie:

```
    if(get_cookie('visible')== 'no') {
        $("#wrapper").hide();
        $(".help").hide();
        $("#slid .show").show();
        $("#slid .hide").hide();
        } else {
            $("#slid .show").hide();
            $("#slid .hide").show();
        }
    $("#slider").click(function() {
        if(get_cookie('visible')== null) {
            set_cookie('visible','no', 2020, 01,01, '/', 'domain.com');
        } else {
            delete_cookie('visible');
        }
            $(".help").slideToggle();
                $("#wrapper").animate({ opacity: 1.0 },200).slideToggle(200, function() {
                    $("#slid img").toggle();
                });
    });
```

Im trying to set the cookie for all pages that exist under domain.com with the path '/'.

However using these functions and jQuery it doesn't appear to be working, any anyone give me an idea of where im going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me, as long as the `domain` is matching or omitted, and there's nothing in `domain` or `path` that gets mangled by `escape()`.

(You shouldn't use `escape()` for the cookie parameters: there is no standard escaping scheme for these. It's generally a bad idea to use `escape()`/`unescape()` for *anything*; it's a non-standard encoding scheme that is not the same as URL-encoding, so if you try to read the cookie from some other language like PHP you won't be able to decode it properly using any built-in function. If you want real URL-encoding for the cookie values themselves, go for `encodeURIComponent`/`decodeURIComponent`, though again, these are still not used for cookie parameters.)

Comment: How can I adjust to add path and domain to make sure and miss the escape problem?

Comment: Just add the `path` and `domain` values straight into the string without calling `escape()` (or anything else) to encode them. (Yes, that does mean it's impossible to have a `path` with a semicolon in.)